# What is the name of this exponential pattern/expression?

Tags: real-analysis, logarithms, exponential-function

This comes from the [Wikipedia on Hoeffdings Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoeffding%27s_lemma). I have never seen the pattern before. It goes like this,

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{b}{b-a}e^{\lambda a} + \frac{-a}{b-a}e^{\lambda b}
&= e^{L(\lambda(b-a))},
\end{align}
$$

where $L(h)= \frac{ha}{b-a}+\ln(1 + \frac{a - e^ha}{b-a})$

I have never seen the $L$ function before and I am wondering if this pattern has a name which refers to it or a nice way to prove that it is true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if it has a name, but there is not really very much to prove, just algebra:
$$
\begin{align}
\exp(L(\lambda(b-a)))
&=
\exp\left(
{a\lambda(b-a)\over b-a}
+\log\left(1+\frac{a - a \exp \lambda (b-a)}{b-a}\right)
\right)
\\
&=\exp(\lambda a) \left(\exp\left(\log\left(1+{a-a\exp \lambda (b-a)\over b-a}\right)\right)\right)\\
&=\exp(\lambda a) \left(1+{a-a\exp \lambda (b-a)\over b-a}\right)\\
&=\exp(\lambda a)\left({b-a\over b-a}+{a-a\exp \lambda (b-a)\over b-a}\right)\\
&={b\exp(\lambda a)\over b-a}
-{a\exp(\lambda b)\over b-a}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Oh thanks. I thought it might be something particular from elsewhere because it just seems like such a weird and random expression to arrive at

Comment: It looks like some kind of "tricky" expression.

Comment: also the expression right before is actually Jensen's inequality but it doesn't state it, so maybe I was primed to look for something hidden